# How to query a document using mongoose and send the document to the client with only one relevant element from an array field to the client?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I have the following schema:

```
var lessonSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    name: String,
    students: [{
        _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        attendance: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false,
        },
    }],
});
```

The students array is an array of students who attended the particular lesson. I want to find a lesson using whether a particular user is present in the students array and then sent only that element of the students array which corresponds to the user making the request, along with all other fields as it is. For example, the query should return:

```
{
  _id: 'objectid',
  name: 'lesson-name'
  students: [details of just the one student corresponding to req.user._id]
}
```

I tried using:

```
Lesson.find({'students._id': String(req.user._id)}, {"students.$": 1})
```

The query returns the document with just the id and the relevant element from the students array:

```
{
_id: 'objectid'
students: [details of the one student corresponding to req.user._id]
}
```

I tried using:

```
Lesson.find({'students._id': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user._id)})
```

This returns the document with the details of all the students:
{
  _id: 'objectid',
  name: 'lesson-name'
  students: [array containing details of all the students who attended the lesson]
}

How can I modify the query to return it the way I want?

Comment: which version of mongodb are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return the **name** field by adding it to the projection object like this:

```
Lesson.find({ "students._id": String(req.user._id) }, { "name": 1, "students.$": 1 })
```

When you add a projection object (2nd parameter to *find*), the **_id** field is returned by default, plus whichever fields you set to **1**.

Therefore, you were returning just the **_id** and the desired student but not the **name** field.

If you want to return all other fields and just limit the array to the matched item then you can make use of **$slice** in your projection:

```
 Lesson.find({ "students._id": String(req.user._id) }, { "students.$": { $slice: 1 } })
```

Comment: I want to return all the fields in the lessons array, not just the name. (The actual document contains many more fields, which have been excluded here to simplify things) Is there a way I can somehow mark the fields which are not to be returned? Marking 16+ fields looks bloated.

Comment: I don’t think you can use inclusion and exclusion together in the projection object. You might have some luck with $slice: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/ ...or perhaps with aggregation: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate

Comment: Try this: Lesson.find({ “students._id”: String(req.user._id) }, { “students.$”: { $slice: 1 } })

Comment: Thanks, that works! Could you update your answer so that I can accept it? :)